# Docker with real-time / low-latency audio? (for virtual amps like Guitarix...)

Tags: audio, docker, real-time, jack, usb-audio

I've been trying to get a foss virtual guitar amp to run on my Fedora machine for a while now, [Guitarix](http://guitarix.org/) (which runs on [JACK](http://jackaudio.org/)) to be more precise. But I just can't figure it out. People say that it is very straight forward to get it to work by using [AV Linux](http://www.bandshed.net/avlinux/) instead. I don't want to install a new distro on my machine, though. So my idea is to create a Docker image based on AV Linux and somehow pass my [USB sound card adapter thingy](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/3M-Guitar-to-PC-USB-Recording-Cable-Lead-Adaptor-Converter-Connection-Interface-6-5mm/32717562427.html) (which I use to connect my guitar) through to the Docker container and then use a VNC tool to interact with the Guitarix GUI in the container. (I also have a [normal USB sound card](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Color-sent-randomly-USB-Sound-Card-USB-Audio-7-1-External-USB-Sound-Card-Audio-Adapter/32602874245.html) that could be used as the output device in case it would help reduce the latency.)

But my fear is that doing this with Docker would introduce a lot of audio latency, effectively rendering it useless. It is really important to me that the delay between picking a string and hearing the sound is as low as possible. A 100 milliseconds for example would be way too much already. 20-30ms would probably be acceptable.

I have already tried it with a virtual machine and the latency was pretty horrible. I have to admit I was using a Windows VM with a different virtual amp (RockSmith) which is very CPU/GPU intensive, though.

Comment: Isn't sound just forwarded with `--device /dev/snd ` during a `run` command?